# Am I doing this wrong? Networking - High Availability: SAN, MSFT Failover Cluster, NIC Teaming

Tags: networking, hyper-v, high-availability, storage-area-network, failovercluster

I have been working in a lab environment to figure out how to design a SAN with a Microsoft failover cluster using multiple NICs, MPIO and iSCSI. I'll try to add as much useful information as I can, please forgive me if I miss any details . . . This is all a new learning experience for me.

**Objective**:
Increase availability/fault tolerance by adding a second path (switch) from each node in the cluster to storage. Allow clients on the network to access to resources/services running in the cluster.

**What I've done so far**:
I have successfully setup and configured a 2-node cluster with MPIO and iSCSI. They share storage via a CSV on a QNAP NAS. Each node has 2 NICs in a Switch Embedded team. Each NIC is connected to one of the switches. Each QNAP ethernet port (there are only 2) is also connected to either one of the switches. I've created the following virtual network adapters in the host OS...

- Management     192.168.1.XX
- CSV            10.10.10.XX
- Live Migration 10.10.40.XX
- iSCSI-01       10.10.20.XX
- iSCSI-02       10.10.30.xx

The switches that I'm using in the lab are pretty basic layer 3 switches. I have done zero config on them as I don't know if there is anything I must do. Everything appears to work okay so long as I have both of the switches linked to each other via an ethernet cable. Since the QNAP only has 2 ethernet ports, I had to create a path for the nodes to get to the QNAP's 2nd iSCSI target on the second switch. Its a janky setup, but it works. I've simulated failures by pulling one of the connections to a node...all good there.

**What I don't know**:
My lab is limited to the nodes, the 2 switches and NAS. I don't know what the proper next steps would be in order to integrate this into a network so clients could access resources in the cluster. If there were just one SAN/"fabric" switch (is that the right term?), no problem. I'd just link that up to another switch that connects to the clients...That's how our current setup is.

At first, I thought that it was just going to work via some sort of magic (that's what networking is like to me), but I feel like I'm missing something. Will there be an issue with the way traffic flows by linking both SAN switches to a single LAN switch? I'm not even sure if that is the "correct" thing to do.

I know that I'm missing a router in this equation . . . Didn't seem to need it for this lab experiment since I wasn't doing any kind of routing. In production we have our network segmented with vlans.

Anyway . . . Here's a diagram of what I'm thinking this will look like in production.
[Network diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BIGL.png).

Edit: Or should I be doing something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fkxK.png)?? Should the SAN connect to the LAN via the SAN switches or should the servers directly connect to the LAN via a switch?

Comment: You should follow the second diagram, as usually in your redundant switch setup you would not want client to have access to them directly as it's for your storage tier. You could make redundant the client switch too, thus it become core switch, and your client switch connect to them in X.  In the switch setup you need to make sure the spanning-tree is on ,so the switch will manage the uplink to make sure only one is active. Create all VLAN for each network on the switch, check for jumbo packet or not depending on the storage tier, etc.. for that matter check the storage best-practice.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me. I take it that you are saying to enable STP on the switch(es) on the LAN side, not the SAN side?

Comment: Could you expand on "you would not want client to have access to them directly as it's for your storage tier"? If we are going to have our network split up using vlans, would it not technically matter anyway?

Comment: What if a loop or DoS happen from that VLAN port ? ..  Goodbye to the switch CPU ?  You always isolate possible human error from your storage switch

Comment: Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

(1) **Storage**. QNAP would make a decent backup target, say used over iSCSI with Veeam, but it's quite a poor choice in terms of the primary storage. Performance isn't great, but the worst part is... It's single controller, so planned or unplanned storage downtime would lead to your whole cluster going down. Not good!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure

(2) **Switches**. For iSCSI they should have a pretty beefy Tx/Rx buffers or you'll see random lock up and I/O latency spikes during heavy load. Would lead to VMs freezing and crashing. Sometimes... These's some good reading on topic:

https://community.arubanetworks.com/discussion/iscsi-and-packet-buffer

https://community.cisco.com/t5/switching/iscsi-switch-recommendations/td-p/1771478

Bottom line is... What you should be doing is getting rid of your current configuration and going 100% hyperconverged setup. Throw in some flash and spindles into your two cluster nodes, either enable Storage Spaces Direct or StarWind Virtual SAN (Free?). These guys both support switchless configuration just fine, so you'll have to direct connect your two cluster nodes with a pair of 10 GbE or 25 GbE NICs with no switched fabric involved! No switch can overrun copper cable in terms of latency and cost! Your existing switches would run upfront connectivity now having two redundant paths from your clients to HCI cluster itself. Very neat design and way more reliable.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/hci/concepts/storage-spaces-direct-overview

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san

Storage Spaces Direct is 1st-class citizen so should be mentioned, but it's rather fragile, requires expensive Datacenter edition, and S2D two-node configuration with nested resiliency can't scale beyond the initial two-node setup. StarWind is way more reliable, works with Standard edition, can be 100% free and scales the way you want.

(3) **Backup**. You can re-purpose QNAP and use free Veeam to handle that. Stick with a 3-2-1 backup rule and you're golden!

https://www.backblaze.com/blog/the-3-2-1-backup-strategy/

https://www.veeam.com/virtual-machine-backup-solution-free.html

Hope this all helped at least a bit...

Comment: Thank you for the input. The QNAP is only used in the lab for testing. In production we will have a much more robust dual controller solution. I'll take a look at your switch recommendations for sure. I'd really love to give S2D a shot, but management has already decided on shared iSCSI storage via a Dell PowerVault.

Comment: Your mgmt has a point. S2D is a square peg in a round hole. Most of the times at least.

Answer (score -1):

Given it is 2023 I would generally question the sanity f this setup to start with. Drop the QNAP, run a high-performance network over 2 switches, us S2D and hyperconvergent setup. You get extreme high uptime and extreme high performance and can use double mirroring for the data.

Your problem in the current setup is that you have still ONE QNAP and if that misbehaves you are off. You also have the problem that unless you run a fast network (that is 25gb upward - 100gb better) you are way below performance of a good local setup.

Switches GENERALLY do not need setup. Use VLAN, isolate that as you see fit, but otherwise it works without. I Run such a setup, every subnet isolated into VLAN's and those go into a low cost router that just handles the routing.

> I can't exactly remember why I did this.

This is literally a "I am off topic here" statement showing a lack of detail and best practices. Advice after that: hire an admin. You do not know by your own admission half of that you do - that is not how you put something in front of a client.

Your diagram is a classical nice single point of failure (in the QNAS) with IIRC one switch too many - from what you show, there is no reason for the rightest switch, you could theoretically just link the 2 switches together, u essentially they should be isolated for the ISCSI traffic. The rightest switch is where the firewall/router is instead of the switch.

What you do not show is how you isolate traffic within the ethernet - vlan etc. - which is in some areas quite critical. IP alone is good, but not good enough for a lot of scenarios.

> Each node has 2 NICs in a Switch Embedded team.

Btw., why? Not the SET - but, why 2 NIC? The boards should have some for low performance, and otherwise - a reason you went with 2 single port and not one dual port ;)

Comment: I appreciate the input!

The crappy little QNAP NAS is only being used in the "lab" because it is what available me. We have a Dell PowerVault waiting to be unboxed. The objective right now is to learn. S2D = Storage Spaces Direct? I'll have to look more into that as I am not familiar with it.

We thought about switching over to SFP28, but we really don't think that we'll saturate that at all in our current environment. We decided to do that in our next upgrade cycle.

Comment: I'm not the only one that works here on the IT team btw . . . I did say my role was more of a junior admin/technician afterall. I did also mention that this is a learning experience . . . sheesh! 

The right most switch is there as part of the LAN . . . It was my way of illustrating connecting the SAN to the LAN. 

I'm not the one odering the NICs, but I would imagine that the LOM is not 10G which it what we're going to be using...10G SFP+.

Comment: If the objective is to learn S2D - you do not need a NAS at all. It is simply not used. I run S2D for a long time and it is amazingly nice. Btw., SFP28 switches are CHEAP - dirt cheap. Check Mikrotik.

Comment: Uh . . . Not buying Mikrotik. Thanks but no thanks. Our department isn't starved of funding.

Comment: Well, not sure you want to hear where I think that puts you - no9t being starved is one thing, WASTING it NEEDLESSLY is another one. "you are fired for cause" level, including reclaiming the wasted funds. Well, that is ethics, for you.

Comment: Mikrotik = junk…

Comment: That is an idea many are finding, and they STILL run large networks flawlessly. Funny, isn't it - maybe the "junk" is more in not knowing the limitations and WHETHER they apply, or - well - a lack of knowlewdge that I find in SO many unprofessionals these days.